# Scala isDefined gets None value even though it has values

Tags: scala, playframework, query-builder

When passing a JSON array to build a sql query, am getting None as value if the name of the column name character exceeds 30 characters. This is the function of my builder.

```
import com.itfsw.query.builder.SqlQueryBuilderFactory
import org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils
import play.api.Logger
import v1.controllers.QueryParserReq

final case class ColumnEmptyException(private val message: String = "",
                                      private val cause: Throwable = None.orNull)
  extends Exception(message, cause)

class QueryParser {
  private val logger = Logger(getClass)

  def parse(json: String): Option[String] = {

    val sqlQueryBuilderFactory = new SqlQueryBuilderFactory
    val sqlBuilder = sqlQueryBuilderFactory.builder

    // build query

    try {
      val sqlQueryResult = sqlBuilder.build(json)
      logger.info(s" conditions $sqlQueryResult")
      Some(sqlQueryResult.getQuery(true))

    }
    catch {
      case ex: Exception =>
        logger.error(ex.getMessage, ex)
        None

    }


  }

  def createQuery(queryReq: QueryParserReq): Option[String] = {
    val select: String = "SELECT "
    val from: String = " FROM "
    val where: String = " WHERE "


    if (queryReq.fields.filter(k => NumberUtils.isNumber(k)).isEmpty &&
      queryReq.fields.nonEmpty
    ) {
      val builder = StringBuilder.newBuilder
      builder.append(select)
      builder.append(queryReq.fields.mkString(","))
      builder.append(from)
      builder.append(queryReq.cubeName.trim)

      println(queryReq.jsCondition)


        //No filters
      if (queryReq.jsCondition.isEmpty) {
        logger.info(s"dynamic Query is $builder")
        Some(builder.toString())
      }

        //with filters
      else {
        val filters = parse(queryReq.jsCondition)
        if (filters.isDefined) {
          builder.append(where)
          builder.append(filters.get)
          logger.info(s"dynamic Query is $builder")
          Some(builder.toString())
        }
        else {
           None
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      None
    }


  }

}
```

my sample payloads

1. Working payload

> ```
> {
>     "filter": "{\"condition\":\"AND\",\"rules\":[{\"field\":\"hospital_id\",\"operator\":\"equal\",\"type\":\"number\",\"value\":\"3\"}]}",
>     "columns": [
>         {
>             "columnName": "Order_status"
>         }
>     ],
>     "groupBy": []
> }
> ```

2. Non workingpayload

> ```
> {
>     "filter": "{\"condition\":\"AND\",\"rules\":[{\"field\":\"orbkn_surgery_procedures_hospital_id\",\"operator\":\"equal\",\"type\":\"number\",\"value\":\"3\"}]}",
>     "columns": [
>         {
>             "columnName": "Order_status"
>         }
>     ],
>     "groupBy": [] }
> ```

And the value of `query.JsCondition` = `{"condition":"AND","rules":[{"field":"booking_id","operator":"equal","type":"number","value":3}]}`

And am using 
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
mysql connector

Comment: The code returning none is the "parse" method, and you don't show this method, so we can't help you.

Comment: @C4stor I have added the method, Any help regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with the maven com.itfsw/QueryBuilder plugin version of the query builder.
I was using

> libraryDependencies += "com.itfsw" % "QueryBuilder" % "1.0.2"

upgrading to

> libraryDependencies += "com.itfsw" % "QueryBuilder" % "1.0.4"

solved the issue